# Get size of terminal window (rows/columns)

Tags: c++, c, shell, terminal

Is there any reliable way of getting the number of columns/rows of the current output terminal window?

I want to retrieve these numbers in a C/C++ program.

I'm looking for a GNU/Linux solution primarily, but also need a Windows solution.

Comment: On Linux, you can also try `stty size`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783988/how-to-get-windows-size-from-linux) might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting terminal width in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022957/getting-terminal-width-in-c)

Comment: Although the 'possible duplicate' covers Unix-like systems, the answers don't cover Windows too, whereas the answers to this question do.  If there is to be 'duplication', the other should be made a duplicate of this (despite being older and more up-voted).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For Unix(-based), use [`ioctl(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) and `TIOCGWINSZ`:

```c
#include <sys/ioctl.h> //ioctl() and TIOCGWINSZ
#include <unistd.h> // for STDOUT_FILENO
// ...

struct winsize size;
ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &size);

/* size.ws_row is the number of rows, size.ws_col is the number of columns. */

// ...
```

Also, while I haven't touched Windows in the last five years, [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo) should help you get the console window size.

Comment: I've read this is not standard POSIX - is there any define that can tell me if the code will work on the current machine?

Comment: Please add back the `#include`s, because this is not a full answer. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022957/getting-terminal-width-in-c

Comment: @DanielCheung Took me a bit, but added the required includes :-)

Answer (score 74):

On Windows, use the following code to print the size of the console window (borrowed from [quantum](/users/1090657)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642749/2589776)):

> ```
> #include <windows.h>
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
> {
>     CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
>     int columns, rows;
>   
>     GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
>     columns = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1;
>     rows = csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 1;
>   
>     printf("columns: %d\n", columns);
>     printf("rows: %d\n", rows);
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

---

On Linux, use the following instead (borrowed from [John T](/users/36457)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1022961/2589776)):

> ```
> #include <sys/ioctl.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <unistd.h>
>
> int main (int argc, char **argv)
> {
>     struct winsize w;
>     ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
>
>     printf ("lines %d\n", w.ws_row);
>     printf ("columns %d\n", w.ws_col);
>     return 0;  // make sure your main returns int
> }
> ```

Comment: Any chance of a cross-platform solution?

Comment: @Raymond you can do a cross-platform solution by using `#ifdef WIN32`, `#else`, `#endif` lines (or something similar). This applies to both the `#include`s and the `code block`s.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution that works in both Windows and Linux:

```c
#if defined(_WIN32)
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define VC_EXTRALEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#elif defined(__linux__)
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#endif // Windows/Linux

void get_terminal_size(int& width, int& height) {
#if defined(_WIN32)
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
    width = (int)(csbi.srWindow.Right-csbi.srWindow.Left+1);
    height = (int)(csbi.srWindow.Bottom-csbi.srWindow.Top+1);
#elif defined(__linux__)
    struct winsize w;
    ioctl(fileno(stdout), TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
    width = (int)(w.ws_col);
    height = (int)(w.ws_row);
#endif // Windows/Linux
}

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int width=0, height=0;
    get_terminal_size(width, height);
    cout << "width=" << width << ", height=" << height << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just tested on macOS 10.15 and the Linux code works just fine for macOS if you changed to `#elif defined(__linux__) || defined(__APPLE__)`

Answer (score 6):

To expand @herohuyongtao answer for Windows. The .srWindow property gives the answer to the size of the console window, i.e. visible rows and cols. This doesn't say what is the actual available screen buffer width and height, which could be larger if window contains scroll bars. If this is the case, use .dwSize:

```
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO sbInfo;
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &sbInfo);
int availableColumns = sbInfo.dwSize.X;
int availableRows = sbInfo.dwSize.Y;
```

Answer (score 3):

After much grief:

```
  auto const w(WEXITSTATUS(std::system("exit `tput cols`")));
  auto const h(WEXITSTATUS(std::system("exit `tput lines`")));
```

Answer (score 2):

On GNU/Linux using libtermcap (https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_mono/termcap.html) create demo.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <term.h>

static char term_buffer[2048];

void
init_terminal_data (void)
{

  char *termtype = getenv ("TERM");
  int success;

  if (termtype == NULL)
    fprintf (stderr, "Specify a terminal type with `setenv TERM <yourtype>'.\n");

  success = tgetent (term_buffer, termtype);
  if (success < 0)
    fprintf (stderr, "Could not access the termcap data base.\n");
  if (success == 0)
    fprintf (stderr, "Terminal type `%s' is not defined.\n", termtype);
}

int
main ()
{
  init_terminal_data ();
  printf ("Got: Lines: %d, Columns: %d\n", tgetnum ("li"), tgetnum ("co"));
  return 0;
}
```

Then compile with `gcc -o demo.x demo.c -ltermcap` and run to give:

```
$ ./demo.x
Got: Lines: 24, Columns: 80
```

I doubt this helps much on Windows though, I don't know that platform.

(Some of this code is copied straight from the termcap documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369503/get-size-of-terminal-window-rows-columns#comment35795982_23369503), you can find the terminal size in shell scripts using `stty size`.

This works on Linux, and also on macOS (Monterey 12.6.6 tested), and by inference on BSD-based platforms.  It is not mandated by [POSIX 2018](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) AFAICT.  It prints the screen size as "rows cols" (two numbers separated by white space).

For example, when run in a rather large window (with 65 rows by 207 columns) on a big screen, I got the output:

```
$ stty size
65 207
$
```

On both Linux and macOS, `stty` objects if standard input is not a terminal and writes an error message to standard error (even if, for example, standard error is connected to a terminal).  You can work around that with `-F /dev/stderr` (or another named file) if need be, but you'll still get an error if `ioctl(fd, TIOCGWINSZ, &winsz)` fails.  You may actually find a use for the shell test operator `[ -t 0 ]` (or `1` or `2`) — which tests whether the numbered file descriptor is a terminal.

A [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18784302/15168) by [hek2gml](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) mentions that you can use:

```
$ tput lines
65
$ tput cols
207
$
```

You can only get one number at a time.