# Get console width in Rust

Tags: rust, console

When line-wrapping our output so it is visually pleasant, it would be helpful knowing the console window or at least the buffer width.

There are answers how to do this in [C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812224/getting-terminal-size-in-c-for-windows) and [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369503/get-size-of-terminal-window-rows-columns), C# even has properties which make this task easy. But Rust?

Is there anything I could use to get this information, or should I just let the user decide where my program wraps the output?

Comment: as for C and C++, you need specific OS feature, you should look at crates.io to find something that will help you

Comment: Found three crates which look interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple crates able to determine terminal width. Which one to use might depend on the exact relevant requirements for each situation. A good starting point might be to check out [termion](https://lib.rs/termion), which also provides a bunch of other useful low-level terminal handling functionality.

As can be seen on the linked page above, it supports multiple platforms. Yet anyone on Microsoft Windows should note that their platform is not mentioned:

There is also the [termsize](https://lib.rs/termsize) crate, which intends to no nothing more than determining the terminal size. This crate has an even wider platform support, and does work with Microsoft Windows.

After updating `Cargo.toml` dependencies, retrieving the terminal width (and height) with these two crates are as trivial as:

```
fn main() {
    let (x, y) = termion::terminal_size().unwrap();
    let termsize::Size {rows, cols} = termsize::get().unwrap();
    println!("          width  height");
    println!("termion:  {:4}    {:4}", x, y);
    println!("termsize: {:4}    {:4}", cols, rows);
}
```